# Proposed tag synonyms for the prepositions tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-synonyms

I created tag synonym suggestions to map the barely used and completely undescribed tags [for](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/for),[of](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/of),[by](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/by),[from](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/from), [with](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/with) to our tag [prepositions](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/prepositions). Its description already includes all the words and there is clearly no use for the single tags and the usual *prepositions* questions encompass questions regarding the other prepositions either way.

The synonyms will be accepted by two up votes on the [preposition synonyms](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/prepositions/synonyms) page.

EDIT: At the readers who up vote this question. Please head over to the synonyms page and up vote the tag synonyms there as well. ;)

EDIT 2: We did it :)

Comment: Huh, tag synonyms. That thing that [has never](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127459) really worked quite as intended but [despite](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/197656) [various](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103211) [reform](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/202754) [proposals](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210617) remains with us. Usually it's much faster for moderators to take care of tag synonyms and merges directly.

Comment: @choster does it really not work? I'd tried to vote on some, but it says I hadn't enough votes on that topic. But we should have more than enough users that have enough votes on the prepositions tag.

Comment: Actually I could vote on one where I had enough votes.

Comment: I had a look, there are tons of users who can vote on the prepositions synonyms. ([Query](https://data.stackexchange.com/english/revision/531588/672256/possible-prepositions-voters))

Comment: 1- Voted!! Go vote who can!!
2- how did you get to that link? I've never been able to find such a place to vote; the link did the trick.

Comment: @Mitch that's really ****** (fill this with expletive at your discretion) to find. 1. Go to tags 2. scroll to bottom, click tag synonyms 3. click specific tag 4. Try to forget all the other ways you think should lead you there (I just needed at least a dozen clicks to re-find it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll accept this to mark the issue concluded.